# ElasticSearch throws 403 on PUT when running App from server, but works when running on local machine

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am posting data into ElasticSearch using RestTemplate:

```
 String elasticUrl = "localhost:9200/" + route + "/_bulk";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(json,headers);
    LOG.info("Sendin data to elastic url: " + elasticUrl + "\n" + request.getBody());

    ResponseEntity<String> response;
    try{
         response = restTemplate.exchange(elasticUrl,HttpMethod.PUT,request,String.class);
         LOG.info("Response from elastic:\n" + response.getBody());
    }catch(Exception e ) {
        LOG.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The elastic runs on remote server ( i have ssh tunnel so i am using localhost ). This works as it should, however when i deploy the app on server where elastic runs, this throws

> 403 - Forbidden

However using curl from that server works just fine. I have not found any reason why the API should behave differently on local machine vs when its deployed. What could be the reason for this behavior?

If something was messed up in elastic configuration, the curl from server wouldnt work either.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the protocol in the URL (http://).

```
  String elasticUrl = "http://localhost:9200/" + route + "/_bulk";
```

If that doesn't help, enable wire logging by setting `org.apache.http.wire` to `DEBUG` and see what headers are being sent to the server and what the exact response is.

Comment: that was typo, the http protocol is specified,